# Set slide subtitle in beamer after \framebreak

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

I am writing my thesis' slides. I need to set a subtitle in some slides, but I am using the `[allowframebreaks]` option and `\framebreak`.

When I set the `\framesubtitle{}` after `\framebreak`, the subtitle is set to all the slides in the `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]` environment and not only in the slide where I set the subtitle.

Is there any way to set the subtitle of only one slide when using `allowframebreaks`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the subtitle changes which is an indicator that it's a different slide, why not using two different slides?

Answer (score 1):

Wanting a subtitle to change for a slide with forced break seems to me as a non-sense.

The easest and most logical way is to end the first slide completely. The you can start a new one with the same title and a different subtitle.